# is Solr 4.0 capable of using join for sorting documents?

Tags: solr

I would like to sort docs using a value in a different Solr core. The use case is fairly standard: I have a movie catalog (slowly updated) and a set of personal movie recommandations, which  are calculated each day and are expressed as float values. Currently I have to denormalize all these values in DIH (big join in the SQL query) and reload the full index (one doc = one movie) each day, which is an heavy burden. I'd like to index the daily recommandations in a second core and keep sorting on the float value.

Solr 4.0 join feature allow for filtering data (fq param): does it also work with sort? if yes what is the exact syntax?

Comment: You might consider using the [ExternalFileField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html) in Solr. Here is a good walk through for how to set it up - [ExternalFileField in Solr](http://www.findwise.com/blog/externalfilefield-in-solr/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Paige. I thought it was a good idea until I remembered that I also need to display the recommendation score in the returned documents. But "Fields of this type may currently only be used as a ValueSource in a FunctionQuery.", as the solr doc states.

Comment: Actually the latest Solr 4.0 documentation states they are available for display - "External fields are not searchable. They can be used only for function queries or display." - http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes

Comment: I know this is old, but did you find a solution? You cannot sort by joined fields, right (when doing a simple JOIN)?

Comment: I Robin, I must say we stopped searching for a solution.